# bash: how to remove a list entry inside a function?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, function

1. How to remove an entry from the list in a function?
2. Why [the hell] does `push_list` work as expected while `pop_list`
   does not?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a the_list=()

push_list() {
    the_list[${#the_list[@]}]="`echo $@`"
}

pop_list() {
    local -i n=${#the_list[@]}
    (( n > 0 )) || return
    let n-=1
    echo ${the_list[$n]}
    unset the_list[$n]
}

cleanup() {
    echo Cleanup...
    local x=$(pop_list)
    while [ -n "$x" ]; do
        echo "/$x/"
        x=$(pop_list)
    done
    echo ...cleaned.
}

trap cleanup EXIT

echo Start.

push_list aaa bbb ccc
push_list qqq www eee
push_list mmm nnn bbb

declare -p the_list

echo End.

# EOF #
```

Comment: What is `push_list` supposed to do, add `aaa bbb ccc` as one element, or add `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc` as three separate elements? If it's the former, `push_list () { the_list+=("$*"); }`; if the latter, `push_list () { the_list+=("$@"); }`.

Comment: But if `push_list` is really only supposed to add *one* item, be explicit about it, and don't rely on `bash` to join multiple elements into one string based on the value of `IFS`: `push_list () { the_list+=("$1"); }` and `push_list "aaa bbb ccc"`.

Comment: If you are using `bash` 4.3 or later, you can simply write `pop_list () { echo "${the_list[-1]}"; unset the_list[-1]; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're spawning a process in `cleanup()`:

```
$(pop_list)
```

I think that it pops from the copy of the list that is in the child.

Comment: So, does `$(xxx)` mean a subshell process?  
It explains everything :(

Answer (score 0):

As it often happens, I've found an answer to **one** of questions:

```js
#!/bin/bash

declare -a the_list=()

push_list() {
    the_list[${#the_list[@]}]="`echo $@`"
}

pop_list() {
    local -i n=${#the_list[@]}
    (( n > 0 )) || return
    let n-=1
    echo ${the_list[$n]}
    unset the_list[$n]
}

cleanup() {
    echo Cleanup...
#    local x=$(pop_list)
#    while [ -n "$x" ]; do
#        echo "/$x/"
#        x=$(pop_list)
#    done
    while (( ${#the_list[@]} > 0 )); do
        local -i i=${#the_list[@]}
        let i-=1
        local x=${the_list[$i]}
        echo "/$x/"
        unset the_list[$i]
    done
    echo ...cleaned.
}

trap cleanup EXIT

echo Start.

push_list aaa bbb ccc
push_list qqq www eee
push_list mmm nnn bbb

declare -p the_list

echo End.

# EOF #
```

Which means that something strange occurs to the variable scoping in nested calls and/or traps...